# How do I Make a Three-Column Title?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, titles

I'm trying to format a title for my document. Normally, I write `<Title> \hfill \today`, to have a title nicely split into two columns, each aligned at the left and right margin, respectively.

Now I want to add my name into the middle, i.e. I want to split the title into three columns: aligned left, center, and right. How do I do this? I tried `tabbing`, but I don't know how to configure the `hspace{}` correctly to get three columns of equal length.

Comment: Can you make a rough example of what you wish?

Comment: Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? This will give us an indication of the type of usage (in the header, in the `\title`, ...).

Comment: @Werner I'm not using any special formatting to make the title: after \begin{document}, I'm just manually writing \Large{Title of Document \hfill \today}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the easiest way of doing it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent
{\large Title of Document \hfill
  An Author \hfill
  \today\par}

\noindent
{\large \makebox[0pt][l]{Title of Document} \hfill
  \makebox[0pt][c]{An Author} \hfill 
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\today}\par}

\end{document}
```

Note that the first option inserts equal spacing between the left and right entries. This would only center the `An Author` if they are of equal width (not always the case). The second option centers the content regardless of the length of the left/right component. Since each component is placed in a box of width `0pt`, overlapping could occur, but I'm not sure whether this is a concern. Of course, that can be updated, if needed.

Note also that `\large` is a switch and not a macro (taking an argument). So, I've included it inside `{`...`}`. Also ending it with a paragraph break to allow for proper vertical alignment/spacing due to a different`\baselineskip`.

`\noindent`, of course, removes the regular paragraph indent inserted for regular paragraph text.

Comment: I had found the first option by experimentation, but the second is exactly what I was looking for. Thank You!